# Flexbox rearrange orders in between 2 nested items

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flexbox that has 2 boxes on the left and 1 box on the right.  I need for the box on the right to wedge between the two boxes on the left.

[EDIT:Clarification]Box 3 should fully expand to consume the same space as boxes 1 and 2 on the left side.[/EDIT]

```css
.rowParent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-content: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
}
.flexChild {
  flex: 1;
  -webkit-align-self: auto;
  -ms-flex-item-align: auto;
  align-self: auto;
}
.flexChild2 {
  flex: 1 100%;
  -webkit-align-self: auto;
  -ms-flex-item-align: auto;
  align-self: auto;
}
#columnChild41158 {
  background-color: green;
  order: 1;
}
#columnChild61714 {
  background-color: red;
  order: 3;
}
#rowChild24054 {
  background-color: blue;
  order: 2;
}
@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  .columnParent {
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .flexChild2 {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="flexChild rowParent">
  <div id="rowChild71124" class="flexChild2 columnParent">
    <div id="columnChild41158" class="flexChild">1</div>
    <div id="columnChild61714" class="flexChild">2</div>
  </div>
  <div id="rowChild24054" class="flexChild">3</div>
</div>
```

Here's a codepen of what I am trying to do:

http://codepen.io/ants/pen/rLYVPa

Currently it is:

```
1       3        
2
```

Once the browser is under 1000px I want it to stack as 100% width items but as:

```
1
3
2
```

I tried using order but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What about display: inline-block?

Comment: Can you set fixed height on container?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is other way to do this unless you set fixed height on flex container. To change order of elements you can't have nested elements in you HTML.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}
.content {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.box {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.last {
  flex: 1;
  background: lightblue;
}
@media(max-width: 768px) {
  .box {
    flex: 1;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .last {
    order: 2;
  }
  .second {
    order: 3;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="box first">1</div>
  <div class="box second">2</div>
  <div class="box last">3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can remove the extra wrapper div to make all flex items at the same level, you can do it with `flex-flow: column nowrap;` and `flex-flow: row wrap;` in the media queries, plus `order` and `width` tricks.

```css
.rowParent {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
}
.flexChild {
  width: 100%;
}
.flexChild2 {
  order: 1;
}
@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  .rowParent {
    flex-flow: row wrap;
  }
  .flexChild {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
.flexChild1 { background-color: lightgreen; }
.flexChild2 { background-color: lightpink; }
.flexChild3 { background-color: lightblue; }
```

```html
<div class="rowParent">
  <div class="flexChild flexChild1">1</div>
  <div class="flexChild flexChild2">2</div>
  <div class="flexChild flexChild3">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: How would you make 3 fully extend down to match the space consumed by 1 and 2?

Comment: Is using javascript an option? I think you might need it.

Comment: It is, but I was hoping to figure out a purely CSS solution.